# Inserting images to PDF using javascript and wicked_pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, wicked-pdf

I want to create a PDF-file from a page of my application. Everything works fine with WickedPdf, except for the images. The page consists of several dynamically created tables with images in these tables. However, I don't know how to use the wicked_pdf_image_tag in my javascript file. I tried adding:

```
<% Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval { include WickedPdfHelper} %>
```

Hoping this would work:

```
var foobar = '<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag("Indicator-missing.png") %>'
$(foobar).appendTo("."+arraynotsynced[i]+"name");
```

But still the wicked_pdf_image_tag doesn't seem to work in my javascript. Is there any other way how I could dynamically insert images in my PDF-file using WickedPdf?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to use javascript for PDF creation?

Comment: To insert dynamically created tables, which contain images of logo's.

Comment: So insert them in your view without Javascript

Comment: Problem is already solved, thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should share your solution with the community

Comment: Used a hack with hidden_fields, not really useful for the community I suppose. Thanks again for your awesome help!!

Comment: Not sure why you would do that. Wicked PDF just needs normal HTML and CSS